# Data not matching schema between xml schema and csv

Tags: xml, csv

I have a schema of

```
<schema>
<entities>
    <entity name="Organization" create="" update="">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="#vendorId" />
            <attribute name="taxId" />
            <attribute name="legalName" />
            <attribute name="contractNumber" />
            <attribute name="#organizationType.code" />
            <attribute name="legalStatus" />
        </attributes>
    </entity>
    <entity name="Organization.addresses" create="" update="">
        <attributes>    
            <attribute name="?vendorId" />  
            <attribute name="#addressType.code" />  
            <attribute name="line1" />  
            <attribute name="line2" />  
            <attribute name="city" />   
            <attribute name="state" />  
            <attribute name="zip" />                            
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entities>
</schema>
```

and my csv file says

```
#vendorId,taxId,legalName,contractNumber,#organizationType.code,legalStatus,#addressType.code,?vendorId,line1,line2,city,state,zip
1,2,Legal Name,12345,3,Pending,business,1,123 fake street,home,fakeville,nb,e2e1j4
```

the software I am using it throwing out the error that

```
Error : Schema and Data does not match
```

I have not worked with xml and csv's much before so I am not sure where my error is. any help is appreciated.

The tool used is [ELM Solutions Passport](http://www.wkelmsolutions.com/products/passport)

Comment: Well, what software are you using? That's likely to be the key here.

Comment: http://www.wkelmsolutions.com/products/passport

Comment: Not sure if the order matters for that tool but in your schema you have ?vendorId and then #addressType.code but they are reversed in order in the CSV file.